# MySQL Search for newest entry for specific column cell strings

Tags: php, mysql, unique

I'm very new to MySQL and PHP, and I want to make my page tell me the newest entry for each name, but not just the newest entry for the table.

The table looks something like this,

```
55 | Curtis | present | 2014-06-22
87 | Curtis | present | 2014-06-22
56 | James  | absent  | 2014-08-25
57 | Curtis | late    | 2014-08-25
48 | Will   | present | 2014-08-25
47 | James  | present | 2014-08-18
43 | Will   | present | 2014-08-18
```

I want it to output like this,

```
43 | Will   | present | 2014-08-25
47 | James  | present | 2014-08-25
57 | Curtis | late    | 2014-08-25
```

Would anybody be able to help me?

Comment: [Have you tried anything](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: You may need to ask this in another site of the network, http://dba.stackexchange.com/ as this site is for programming issues.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how I would do it. I would like to get it so that MySQL does the processing, but if I have to do it in PHP, ok.

Comment: @MosheKatz You're probably right, will read that.

Comment: @CurtisAlcock shouldn't the latest for James be `absent  | 2014-08-25` and for Will be `present | 2014-08-25` or what is the other criteria you're using the entry id? if id also plays a role then Curtis would be wrong.

Comment: @CurtisAlcock You should take the time to look for a good SQL tutorial. Google around a bit, there are lots of 'em

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `id` is incremental (that is, more recent records have bigger `id` values), this can be solved by using a nested query that gets the max values of `id` for each `name`:

```sql
select a.*
from yourTable as a
     inner join (
         select max(id) as max_id 
         from yourTable 
         -- Add any WHERE conditions here (for example: WHERE status='present')
         group by name
     ) as b on a.id = b.max_id
-- WHERE conditions go here
-- ORDER BY columns go here
```

Comment: @MosheKatz Because I see the posibility that a single `name` can have more than one record in a single day. Given the (very) limited info provided by the OP, I'd like to "play it safe".